# why url works in browser but not using requests get method

Tags: python, url, python-requests, urllib, urldecode

while testing, I just discovered, that this

```
url = ' http://wi312.rockdizfile.com/d/uclf2kr7fp4r2ge47pcuihdpky2chcsjur5nrds2hx53f26qgxnrktew/Kimbra%20-%20Love%20in%20High%20Places.mp3'
```

works in browser and file download begins but if i try to fetch this file using

```
requests.get(url)
```

it gives massive error ...

any clue why is this happening ? do in need to decode this to make it working?

*Update*
this is the error I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "python/file_download.py", line 98, in _downloadChunk
    stream=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 485, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 381, in send
    raise Timeout(e)
Timeout: (<requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x10258de90>, 'Connection to wi312.rockdizfile.com timed out. (connect timeout=0.001)')
```

there was no space when I posted, it was just in newline because I posted inline code embed.

Here is the code that makes requests:(also try new URL: `http://archive.org/download/LucyIsabelleMarsh/LucyIsabelleMarsh-ItalianStreetSong.mp3`)

```
import requests
import signal
import sys
import time
import threading
import utils as _fdUtils
from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout

def _downloadChunk(url, idx, irange, fileName, sizeInBytes):
    _log.debug("Downloading %s for first chunk %s " % (irange, idx+1))
    pulledSize = irange[-1]
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False,  timeout=0.001,
                            headers={'Range': 'bytes=%s-%s' % (str(irange[0]), str(irange[-1]))}, 
                            stream=True)
    except (SocketTimeout, requests.exceptions), e:
        _log.error(e)
        return


    chunk_size = str(irange[-1])
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size):
        status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (pulledSize, pulledSize * 100. / int(chunk_size))
        status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
        sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % status)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        pulledSize += len(chunk)
        dataDict[idx] = chunk
        time.sleep(.03)
        if pulledSize == sizeInBytes:
            _log.info("%s downloaded %3.0f%%", fileName, pulledSize * 100. / sizeInBytes)

class ThreadedFetch(threading.Thread):
    """ docstring for ThreadedFetch
    """
    def __init__(self, saveTo, queue):
        super(ThreadedFetch, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.__saveTo = saveTo

    def run(self):
        threadLimiter.acquire()
        try:
            items = self.queue.get()
            url = items[0]
            split = items[-1]
            fileName = _fdUtils.getFileName(url)

            # grab split chunks in separate thread.
            if split > 1:
                maxSplits.acquire()
                try:

                    sizeInBytes = _fdUtils.getUrlSizeInBytes(url)
                    if sizeInBytes:
                        byteRanges = _fdUtils.getRangeSegements(sizeInBytes, split)
                    else:
                        byteRanges = ['0-']
                    filePath = os.path.join(self.__saveTo, fileName)

                    downloaders = [
                        threading.Thread(
                            target=_downloadChunk, 
                            args=(url, idx, irange, fileName, sizeInBytes),
                        )
                        for idx, irange in enumerate(byteRanges)
                        ]

                    # start threads, let run in parallel, wait for all to finish
                    for th in downloaders:
                        th.start()

                    # this makes the wait for all thread to finish
                    # which confirms the dataDict is up-to-date
                    for th in downloaders:
                        th.join()
                    downloadedSize = 0
                    with open(filePath, 'wb') as fh:
                        for _idx, chunk in sorted(dataDict.iteritems()):
                            downloadedSize += len(chunk)
                            status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (downloadedSize, downloadedSize * 100. / sizeInBytes)
                            status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
                            fh.write(chunk)
                            sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % status)
                            time.sleep(.04)
                            sys.stdout.flush()
                            if downloadedSize == sizeInBytes:
                                _log.info("%s, saved to %s", fileName, self.__saveTo)
                    self.queue.task_done()
                finally:
                    maxSplits.release()
```

Comment: @doniyor: your edit was not helpful in that it removed the quotes from the string value; those are required in Python and you destroyed the evidence as to what the problem is here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, there was a space after the first quote

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, which is why I rolled back and re-applied the edit properly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh my bad, i thought it was an attemp to highlight. sorry

Comment: @san: **Always** include the full traceback in your question. *it gives massive error* is **not** a helpful bug report.

Comment: Yes, please provide the error.

Comment: Post your code that is making the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback is showing a `Timeout` exception, and in your code indeed you have a very short timeout set, either remove this limit or increase it:

```
requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False,  timeout=0.001, # <-- this is very short
```

Even if you were accessing localhost (your own computer), such a timeout will result in a Timeout exception. From the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts):

> Note
>
> timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather,
>   an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for
>   timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the
>   underlying socket for timeout seconds).

So its not doing what you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space before the start of the url which causes a `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema` error:

```
url = ' http://wi312.rockdizfile.com/d/uclf2kr7fp4r2ge47pcuihdpky2chcsjur5nrds2hx53f26qgxnrktew/Kimbra%20-%20Love%20in%20High%20Places.mp3'
```

Change to:

```
url = 'http://wi312.rockdizfile.com/d/uclf2kr7fp4r2ge47pcuihdpky2chcsjur5nrds2hx53f26qgxnrktew/Kimbra%20-%20Love%20in%20High%20Places.mp3'
```