# requests.get times out for url that returns instantly in the browser

Tags: python, python-requests

What would cause requests.get to timeout, when the url works in the browser?

I've seen the response at [requests.get returns 403 while the same url works in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946166/requests-get-returns-403-while-the-same-url-works-in-browser) which talks about masking the User-Agent, but my issue is that I get a TimeoutError, not that it's forbidden. I tried it anyway, and it didn't help.

```
import requests

def onemap_geocode(postalcode):
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    onemap_request = 'https://developers.onemap.sg/commonapi/search?searchVal=' + str(postalcode) + '&returnGeom=Y&getAddrDetails=N'
    print(onemap_request)
    response = requests.get(onemap_request,headers=header)
    print('response obtained')
    response_json = response.json
    lat = response_json['results'][0]['LATITUDE']
    lon = response_json['results'][0]['LONGITUDE']

    return lat + ', ' + lon

onemap_geocode(178880)
```

Comment: I tried and don't get timeout. But you should update the line `esponse_json = response.json` by `response_json = response.json()`, because it can not works like this.

Comment: Well, the problem might be on your side, I got the result almost immediately

Comment: I managed to get a result on my personal pc on my own network, so I'm beginning to suspect that the network at work is blocking the response somehow. The tech support here isn't great, however, so I need to identify what it is that is causing it to fail when I make the API call like this, but it works in the browser, even with the header masking. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a large number in timeout:

```
response = requests.get(onemap_request,headers=header,timeout=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

`response_json = response.json`

You are missing the parenthesis when calling the `response.json` method. This line should be changed to `response_json = response.json()`.

Other than that your code works as expected.