# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden for urlretrieve

Tags: python

I try to download a image from a website but I get an error. Can somebody help me and explain what is going on and how could I make a work around?

Sorry I'm completely new to programming stuff with websites.

```
def downloadImage(url, name, path=f'./', fileFormat='.jpg'):
    fullPath = path + name + fileFormat
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullPath)

downloadImage('https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23', 'test')
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\felix\OneDrive\Desktop\Programmieren\Python\Projekte\PlayGround\Manga\manganeloAPI.py", line 106, in <module>
    downloadImage('https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23', 'test')
  File "c:\Users\felix\OneDrive\Desktop\Programmieren\Python\Projekte\PlayGround\Manga\manganeloAPI.py", line 86, in downloadImage
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullPath)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

A work around I tried is using requests:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
with open(fullPath, 'wb') as outfile: 
    outfile.write(r.content)
```

This makes a test.jpg appear where I want it too, but if I open it I get:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<title>Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds - Manganelo</title>
<meta name="description" content="Read Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds - Every few centuries, 496 demons of the demon world, each choose a human who will fight each other in a tournament of sorts called &ldquo;Diabloli&rdquo;. Our main protagonist is a little high " />
<meta name="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds, read Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds manga, Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds raw, Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds manga online, Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds scans" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright © 2019 MangaNelo" />
<meta name="Author" content="Manganelo" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="Manganelo" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds - Manganelo" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Read Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds - Every few centuries, 496 demons of the demon world, each choose a human who will fight each other in a tournament of sorts called &ldquo;Diabloli&rdquo;. Our main protagonist is a little high " />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://avt.mkklcdnv6.com/33/f/18-1583498372.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds - Manganelo" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://avt.mkklcdnv6.com/33/f/18-1583498372.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Read Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds - Every few centuries, 496 demons of the demon world, each choose a human who will fight each other in a tournament of sorts called &ldquo;Diabloli&rdquo;. Our main protagonist is a little high " />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="https://manganelo.com/" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://manganelo.com/favicon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="https://manganelo.com/favicon-16x16.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://manganelo.com/favicon-32x32.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="https://manganelo.com/favicon-96x96.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/css/c-style.css?v=01012021" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/css/owl.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/css/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/css/tooltip.css?v=01012021" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/css/c-style-search.css?v=01012021" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,vietnamese' rel='stylesheet' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/custom.js?v=01012021"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/tooltip.js?v=01012021"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/fsearch.js?v=01012021"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://manganelo.com/themes/starrate/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/starrate/js/starwarsjs.js"></script>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1664224760511779" />
<script>
    baseurljs = 'https://manganelo.com/';
        tooltypejs = '';
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/css/c-style-chapter.css?v=1.1.4">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/custom-chapter.js?v=1.1.4"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/lazysizes.min.js'></script>
<script>
            var $navi_change_chapter_address = 'https://manganelo.com/' + 'chapter/oa919470/chapter_';
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body-site">
<div class="container">
<div class="panel-logo-chapter">
<a href="https://manganelo.com/" title="Read Manga Online">
<img src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/images/logo-chap.png" alt="Read Manga Online - manganelo" title="Read Manga Online - manganelo" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="panel-breadcrumb">
<a class="a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/" title="Read Manga Online">Read Manga Online</a>
<span>»</span>
<a class="a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/manga/oa919470" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba">Yuko Sae Tatakaeba</a>
<span>»</span>
<a class="a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23" title="Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds">Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds</a>
</div>
<div class="panel-navigation">
<select class="navi-change-chapter"><option data-c="23" selected>Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds</option><option data-c="22">Vol.3 Chapter 22: Soirée</option><option data-c="21">Vol.3 Chapter 21: Change Of Seats</option><option data-c="20">Chapter 20: The Nemesis</option><option data-c="19">Vol.2 Chapter 19: Special Training</option><option data-c="18">Vol.2 Chapter 18: Confrontation</option><option data-c="17">Vol.2 Chapter 17: Cinema</option><option data-c="16">Vol.2 Chapter 16: Shopping</option><option data-c="15">Vol.2 Chapter 15: Name</option><option data-c="14">Vol.2 Chapter 14: Finger Tag</option><option data-c="13">Vol.2 Chapter 13: Kasumi</option><option data-c="12">Vol.2 Chapter 12: Organization</option><option data-c="11">Vol.2 Chapter 11: Messenger</option><option data-c="10">Vol.2 Chapter 10: Friends</option><option data-c="9">Vol.1 Chapter 9: Aspirations</option><option data-c="8">Vol.1 Chapter 8: Fried Foods</option><option data-c="7">Vol.1 Chapter 7: Cleaning</option><option data-c="6">Vol.1 Chapter 6: The Fight</option><option data-c="5">Vol.1 Chapter 5: Casual Encounter</option><option data-c="4">Vol.1 Chapter 4: Photography</option><option data-c="3">Chapter 3: Demon</option><option data-c="2">Chapter 2: Prodigy</option><option data-c="1">Chapter 1: Opening</option></select><div class="navi-change-chapter-btn"><a rel="nofollow" class="navi-change-chapter-btn-prev a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_22"><i></i>PREV CHAPTER</a></div> </div>
<div class="panel-chapter-info-top">
<h1>YUKO SAE TATAKAEBA VOL.3 CHAPTER 23: DEMONIC BONDS</h1>
<div class="server-image">
<p class="server-image-caption">Image shows slow or error, you should choose another IMAGE SERVER</p>
<span style="font-size: 12px;">
<span style="display: block;">
<span class="server-image-name">IMAGES SERVER: </span>
<a rel="nofollow" class="server-image-btn isactive">1</a>
 <a data-l='https://manganelo.com/content_server_s2' rel="nofollow" class="server-image-btn a-h">2</a>
</span>
<span style="display: block;">
<span class="server-image-name" style="margin-left: 10px;">LOAD ALL IMAGES AT ONCE:</span>
<label class="label-switch label-switch-on" data-l='https://manganelo.com/content_lazyload_on'>
<span class="switch-front"></span>
<span class="switch-end"></span>
</label>
</span>
<span style="display: block;">
<span class="server-image-name">IMAGES MARGIN: </span>
<select class="server-cbb-content-margin">
<option value="0">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;overflow: hidden;text-align: center;">
<div style="text-align: center; max-width: 620px; max-height: 270px; margin: 10px auto; overflow: hidden; display: block;">
<iframe src="/ads/bidgear_300x250_desktop_4.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px;height: 250px;float: left;"></iframe>
<iframe src="/ads/adtrue_300x250_desktop.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px;height: 250px;float: left;margin-left: 20px;"></iframe>
</div>

</div>
<div class="container-chapter-reader">
<img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/1.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 1 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 1 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/2.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 2 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 2 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/3.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 3 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 3 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/4.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 4 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 4 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/5.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 5 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 5 - MangaNelo.com" /><div style="text-align: center; max-width: 620px; max-height: 270px; margin: 10px auto; overflow: hidden; display: block;"><iframe src="/ads/bidgear_300x250_desktop_2.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px;height: 250px;float: left;"></iframe><iframe src="/ads/bidgear_300x250_desktop_3.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px;height: 250px;float: left;margin-left: 20px;"></iframe></div><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/6.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 6 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 6 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/7.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 7 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 7 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/8.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 8 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 8 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/9.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 9 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 9 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/10.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 10 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 10 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/11.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 11 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 11 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/12.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 12 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 12 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/13.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 13 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 13 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/14.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 14 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 14 - MangaNelo.com" /><img src="https://s8.mkklcdnv8.com/mangakakalot/o1/oa919470/vol3_chapter_23_demonic_bonds/15.jpg" alt="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 15 - MangaNelo.com" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds page 15 - MangaNelo.com" /> </div>
<div style="max-height: 280px; text-align: center; width: 810px; margin: 10px auto; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%;">
<div style="float: left; max-width: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe src="/ads/bidgear_300x250_desktop.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px;height: 250px;"></iframe>
</div>
<a href="https://manganelo.com/"><img src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/images/gohome.png" style="float: left;width: 200px;height : 200px;" /></a>
<div style="float: left; max-width: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe src="/ads/adtrue_300x250_desktop.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px;height: 250px;"></iframe> </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel-navigation">
<select class="navi-change-chapter"><option data-c="23" selected>Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds</option><option data-c="22">Vol.3 Chapter 22: Soirée</option><option data-c="21">Vol.3 Chapter 21: Change Of Seats</option><option data-c="20">Chapter 20: The Nemesis</option><option data-c="19">Vol.2 Chapter 19: Special Training</option><option data-c="18">Vol.2 Chapter 18: Confrontation</option><option data-c="17">Vol.2 Chapter 17: Cinema</option><option data-c="16">Vol.2 Chapter 16: Shopping</option><option data-c="15">Vol.2 Chapter 15: Name</option><option data-c="14">Vol.2 Chapter 14: Finger Tag</option><option data-c="13">Vol.2 Chapter 13: Kasumi</option><option data-c="12">Vol.2 Chapter 12: Organization</option><option data-c="11">Vol.2 Chapter 11: Messenger</option><option data-c="10">Vol.2 Chapter 10: Friends</option><option data-c="9">Vol.1 Chapter 9: Aspirations</option><option data-c="8">Vol.1 Chapter 8: Fried Foods</option><option data-c="7">Vol.1 Chapter 7: Cleaning</option><option data-c="6">Vol.1 Chapter 6: The Fight</option><option data-c="5">Vol.1 Chapter 5: Casual Encounter</option><option data-c="4">Vol.1 Chapter 4: Photography</option><option data-c="3">Chapter 3: Demon</option><option data-c="2">Chapter 2: Prodigy</option><option data-c="1">Chapter 1: Opening</option></select><div class="navi-change-chapter-btn"><a rel="nofollow" class="navi-change-chapter-btn-prev a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_22"><i></i>PREV CHAPTER</a></div> </div>
<div class="panel-breadcrumb">
<span>
<a class="a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/" title="Read Manga Online">
<span>Read Manga Online</span>
</a>
</span>
<span>»</span>
<span>
<a class="a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/manga/oa919470" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba">
<span>Yuko Sae Tatakaeba</span>
</a>
</span>
<span>»</span>
<span>
<a class="a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23" title="Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic bonds">
<span>Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds</span>
</a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-chapter-comment panel-fb-comment a-h">
<p class="fb-comment-title fb-comment-title-show"><span>Facebook Comments</span><i></i></p>
<div class="fb-comments-content" id="aHR0cDovL21hbmdhbmVsby5jb20vY2hhcHRlci9vYTkxOTQ3MC9jaGFwdGVyXzIz"></div>
</div>
<div class="panel-chapter-info-bot">
<h2>Yuko Sae Tatakaeba Vol.3 Chapter 23: Demonic Bonds Summary</h2>
<p>You're read <a class="a-h" href="https://manganelo.com/manga/oa919470" title="Yuko Sae Tatakaeba">Yuko Sae Tatakaeba</a> manga online at <span>MangaNelo.com</span>. Alternative(s) : ゆこさえ戦えば - Author(s) : Sei Fukui</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container container-footer">
<div class="container-footer-content">
<div class="pn-hot-link">
&nbsp;

</div>
<div class="pn-contacts">
<h4>About Us</h4>
<p>Current Time is Jan 16,2021 - 02:05:41 AM</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    $appidfb = '190712595201460';
    
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + $appidfb;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://manganelo.com/themes/hm/js/changes-mode-chapter.js?v=1.1.4"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 403 generally means the website requires authentication.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps you::

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def save_image(response, name, path=""):
    with open(path + name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)

session = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
    'Accept': '*/*', 
}
session.headers = headers
response = session.get("https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23")
if response.status_code == 200:
    headers["Referer"] = "https://manganelo.com/chapter/oa919470/chapter_23"
    session.headers = headers    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for img in soup.findAll("img"):
        url = img["src"]
        name = url.split("/")[-1]
       
        print(url)
        r = session.get(url)
        print(r)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            save_image(r, name, path="")
        else:
            print("Huston we have a problem....")
else:
    print(responce)
```

For more details [requests.get returns 403 while the same url works in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946166/requests-get-returns-403-while-the-same-url-works-in-browser)