# How to check website title changes with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to check this site for changes on the title:
https://allestoringen.nl/storing/kpn/

```
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
event_string = str(soup.find(text='Er is geen storing bij KPN'))

print (event_string)
```

However, `event_string` returns `None` every time.

Comment: Would you mind posting the relevant html from the site?

Comment: If you can't find it then it's not there. The text on the site for me is: "Mogelijke storing bij KPN"

Comment: Did you check if there was a 'storing' when you ran your code?

Comment: This is your problem (and answer):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946166/requests-get-returns-403-while-the-same-url-works-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't get a result might be that the website doesn't accept your request. I got this result.

```py
page = requests.get(url)

page.status_code  # 403
page.reason       # 'Forbidden'
```

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden) post for a solution.

It is always a good idea to check the return status of your request in your code.

But to solve your problem. You might want to check the `<title>` element instead of a specific string.

```py
# stolen from the post I mentioned
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
page.status_code  # 200. Adding a header solved the problem.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

# get title.
print(soup.find("title").text)
'KPN storing? Actuele storingen en problemen | Allestoringen'
```