# URL working in browser but not in using requests.get method

Tags: python, python-requests

I am facing a very strange behavior of a webpage which I am accessing by python request library. Essentially my code is working ok for one hour or two and a given point stops working.

I was assuming that the server was down and nobody was able to access the webpage, but indeed my browser is still able to access the webpage, meanwhile, I am not any longer able to access using request.

Code is simple:

```
url = "https://www.rememori.com"
data = requets.get(url)
```

This code works ok, but at a given point of time stops working and provides the following output:

```
print(data.text)

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

However, when accessing the webpage with browser or even android everything goes smooth.

I tried to find a similar error and found this recommendation inside StackOverflow: [why url works in browser but not using requests get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097093/why-url-works-in-browser-but-not-using-requests-get-method) and this one: [Python request.get fails to get an answer for a url I can open on my browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154114/python-request-get-fails-to-get-an-answer-for-a-url-i-can-open-on-my-browser/51154676)

Essentially they propose to introduce a header, which I tried and the result is the same

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
data = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: once it starts giving you 502, did it work again? many sites for security will block the IP address but they usually give 403 or so, not server error. you can try to put your request with the session as header you have already tried. `session = requests.Session()
r1 = session.get(url, headers=user_agent)`

Comment: Arg, forgot to answer. So I tried to do it and it failed, I actully tried to run it using different computer wiht network and the same computer in a different network, and gives the same error. Is like website is down for accessing by code.

Comment: No it was working, I retry again, and it got blocked again.